# jQuery - OnLoad Animate Div to close unless hover/active

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I have a div that has the following applied to it on document load:

```
$("#megamenu").delay(3000).animate({height:"hide",opacity:"hide"}, 5000);
```

What I want to be able to do is stop and revert the animation if a user hovers over said div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the jQuery.stop() method to stop the current animation. Then specify the parameters you wish the new animation to return the element to. For example:

```
$("#megamenu").delay(3000).animate({height:"hide",opacity:"hide"}, 5000).mouseover(function() {
    $(this).stop(true, false).animate({height: "100px", opacity: 1}, 1000);
});
```

See: http://api.jquery.com/stop/ for details.

Comment: That did it, thanks - I'd tried multiple variations on that but never the right one! Saved me some headache today!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [.stop()](http://api.jquery.com/stop/) method:

```
$('#megamenu').mouseover(function(ev) {
    this.stop(true, false);
    this.css({ opacity: 1.0 });
    this.css({ height: original_height });
})
```

That will revert the animation immediately. @Archonix was answering the question at the same time showing how to revert with a reverse animation.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#megamenu").delay(3000).animate({height:0,opacity:0}, 5000);

$("#megamenu").mouseover(function(ev) {
    $(this).stop(true,false).animate({height:"450px",opacity:1});
});
```

Where it says height:"450px" replace 450px with whatever size you want it to revert to.

*stop(true,false) stops the animation. (true clears any queued animations and false stops it at it's current state instead of jumping to the end of the animation)*